# Seagate Media to Chromecast

Tags: chromecast

I'm having trouble using the Seagate Media to cast to ChromeCast. I was using this tutorial http://knowledge.seagate.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/006027en?language=tr-tr with no luck. The problem is that in the app, the cast button isn't available.

When using the YouTube App, I haven't got any problem. The phone and Seagate Personal Cloud are on the same Wireless network.

Would there be anyone knowing what I'm missing to use this feature to stream from a Seagate Personal Cloud?

Thanks in advance!